# Value and Focus() not working on dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to create something to refresh the list of dates to all users every 30 seconds.
I dynamically create a table with the list of dates in my database using AJAX, the thing is that the refresh removes what the user was writing in the moment of the refresh so I'm saving what the user writes in javascript global variables, calling the refresh function, then filling the inputs with the information in the variables and focusing the input the user was on.

The thing is the inputs aren't filled nor focused.

this is my relevant code here:

```
var identificacionc = "";
var nombresc = "";
var apellidosc = "";
var telefonoc = "";
var posicionc = 0;
var ladoc = 0;

//This is called on input onfocus to record the id
function recuerdo(posicion, lado)
{
    posicionc = posicion;
    ladoc = lado;
}

function actualizar()
{
    //This line is not relevant
    listaragenda();

    if (document.getElementById("datepicker").value != "")
    {
        //put the info in the global variables and it works even if they're dynamically created
        identificacionc = document.getElementById("txtidentificacion" + posicionc).value;
        nombresc = document.getElementById("txtnombres" + posicionc).value;
        apellidosc = document.getElementById("txtapellidos" + posicionc).value;
        telefonoc = document.getElementById("txttelefono" + posicionc).value;
        //Here is where I call the function to refresh dates
        listarcitas();    
    }
}

function listarcitas()
{
    var objAjax = crearObjeto();
    var fecha = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
    objAjax.open("POST", "clases/listarcitas.php", true);
    objAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    objAjax.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (objAjax.readyState == 4 && objAjax.status == 200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("citaslistadas").innerHTML = objAjax.responseText;
            //Checks if any global variable is not empty to start to fill them with the info
            //nothing inside this If works
            //posicionc and ladoc have the correct values
            if (identificacionc != "")
            {
                document.getElementById("txtidentificacion" + posicionc).value = identificacionc;
                document.getElementById("txtnombres" + posicionc).value = nombresc;
                document.getElementById("txtapellidos" + posicionc).value = apellidosc;
                document.getElementById("txttelefono" + posicionc).value = telefonoc;

                if (ladoc == 1)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtidentificacion" + posicionc).focus();
                }
                else if (ladoc == 2)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtnombres" + posicionc).focus();
                }
                else if (ladoc == 3)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtapellidos" + posicionc).focus();
                }
                else if (ladoc == 4)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txttelefono" + posicionc).focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    objAjax.send("fecha=" + fecha);
}

//the interval every 30s
window.setInterval("actualizar()", 30000);
```

Everything retrieved from AJAX works fine everything is listed, even in the web browser console I make alerts of the variables, set the values and focus the dynamically created inputs, everything works fine.

But why this is not working in the code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez como dije, en consola de firefox por ejemplo hago un alert de todas esas variables y todas me devuelven el valor que deben tener, entonces no es que estén vacías cuando llamo a listar citas

Comment: actualizar() function stores the variables

Comment: the page is not refreshing, I'm using AJAX at listarcitas() to fill a div with the list of dates

Comment: welp, I solved the problem by myself, the if inside listarcitas() wasn't checking for nombresc, apellidosc and telefonoc as well, sometimes identificacionc can be empty. Anyway, thank you